# Surface Reflectance from WorldView-3 CAVIS Bands

Tags: remote-sensing, worldview-3

I am working on a project that focuses specifically on 1 micron-region of the EM spectrum. WorldView-3 CAVIS bands look promising for my work, but as far as I know, they were designed to monitor the atmosphere to improve the quality of images acquired with other bands.

I am wondering if anyone knows whether it is possible to obtain surface reflectance values from CAVIS bands or not.